# Can I get on Airport Express (return) from a nearer station in Hong Kong?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, airport-transfer, hong-kong

I want to purchase Airport Express ticket from Hong Kong Airport to Hong Kong Station, but I consider moving to Kowloon at the end of my trip.

In this case, is it possible to buy a ticket to Hong Kong Station, but ride on the expressrail from Kowloon on the return trip? I don't like to bother to go back to Hong Kong Station.

Comment: The reason for downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently no, according to [Hong Kong MTR](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/tickets/tf_index.html)

> Round Trip tickets are station-specific and can be used for 1 return
>   journey on the Airport Express **between Airport and the station
>   specified**.

On the other hand, why would you want this? Roundtrip from airport to Hong Kong is 180 HKD. However two one-ways airport - Hong Kong and Kowloon - airport is 100 + 90 = 190. So your savings are 10 HKD, a coffee.

However if you really need to save 10 HKD, then do not take Express at all. Take one of the [Airport buses](http://www.nwstbus.com.hk/routes/airport-bus/route/index.aspx?intLangID=1&textOnly=true), which will cost up to 50 HKD. This will be quite slow, but some buses have free Wi-Fi, and you'll see some scenery.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't come up with the two one-way tickets. Thanks. I think $10 is not even worth a coffee, though.